# What happened to Thor's weapon at the end of Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Since Mjolnir had been broken during *Thor: Ragnarok*, Thor needed a new weapon to fight Thanos in *Infinity War*. He

> visits the dwarfs that forged Mjolnir and gets a new weapon, Stormbreaker. One of the attributes of the weapon is that its handle is actually made of Teenage Groot's arm.

At the end of the Movie, Groot

> disappears due to Thanos using the power of the Infinity Stones to kill half of the Universe's population.

Do we see what happened to the weapon at that moment?

> Did the handle disappear?

Comment: This was left unknown if I recall correctly, but seeing as Groot didn't seem to have any control over the handle, or any other parts of his body he's released from him in the past. I don't see why it should fade. Also Groot Jr. Groot died.

Comment: Also, if you want to edit your question ask why the axe is with a purple-ish color à la power gem. (Is not Thanos blood, his blood is red.)

Comment: @Deltab, that would be a new question entirely. I suggest you ask it.

Comment: Not that it proves anything either way, but when Bucky disappeared he took his metal arm with him (but not his gun). So it seems to me like the parts of you that are currently attached would disappear, whereas things that are not attached are left behind.

Comment: @Deltab: “Is not Thanos blood, his blood is red” — it’s probably bits of his chest flesh, as gross as that is.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that it disappears, since Groot cut off his arm, and so it actually isn't really a lifeform anymore but instead is just a part of a weapon.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! While this may answer the question it seems very speculative. Could you [edit] your answer with some more details of why you think this is the case?

Comment: A valid argument though, raises the question whether dead people already in their graves flake away like the living people did...

Comment: @colmde Probably not. If we just erased half the population of the universe entirely randomly and included dead people as members of the population... there would be a reasonable chance that any given living person got erased (there are about 15 dead people for each living one).